# In Datatables.net what is the feature shown on the home page called?

Tags: datatables

I am trying out the datatables.net library and would like to get a similar function as to what is shown on the homepage (and below) where the user can click on the icon and it will expand the row to show the child elements. Where in the documentation can I see where this is done?

[image: Datatables.net home page]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are called "child rows" - see an [official example](https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html) with full code. There are also lots of SO questions about DataTables child rows.